# Using discrete distribution to fit continuous distribution and then reproduce the same discrete distribution, all on the same Plot

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, distributions, discrete

I'm using the discrete distribution function to fit the continuous distribution by method of moments, and then, trying to reproduce the same discrete distribution function.

The data used to plot the discrete distribution is contained in two `Lists` : `II` and `Fexp`. I plot it using the command:

```
p1 = ListPlot[Thread[{II, Fexp}], PlotMarkers -> {marker1, .05}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Molar Mass (g/mol)", "Molar Fraction"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]]
```

Which gives:

[image: discrete distribution]

Using the method of moments I can obtain (fit) the continuous distribution function (`Fanaly`) that represents the same discrete distribution. Having the continuous distribution, I can integrate it between two points centered at the points of the discrete distribution. For the above case, I calculate the integration limits by doing:

```
Ihist = N[Table[(II[[i + 1]] + II[[i]])*0.5, {i, Length[II] - 1}]] ;
```

The integration of the continuous distribution (`Fanaly`) between two points should be the discrete distribution centered between those points, so I obtain the integrated values by doing:

```
Fhist = N[Table[(\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(Ihist[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]\), \
\(Ihist[\([\)\(i + 1\)\(]\)]\)]\(Fanaly[x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)), {i,
      Length[Ihist] - 1}]] ;
```

Now, I have the Histogram heights `Fhist` and the bin delimiters `Ihist`, which I tried to plot following the `Mathematica` reference website:

```
 Histogram[{x1,x2,…},bspec]

plots a histogram with bin width specification bspec.
The following bin width specifications bspec can be given:
    {{b1,b2,…}} use the bins [b1,b2),[b2,b3),…
```

When I try to plot the histogram it gives me a weird plot:

```
Histogram[Fhist, {Ihist}]
```

[image: histogram of integrated continuous distribution]

By using `BarChart` I got a better view, but I cannot set the bin delimiters in the abcissa axis:

```
BarChart[Fhist, AxesLabel -> {"Molar Mass (g/mol)", "Molar Fraction"},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]]
```

[image: BarChart]

Can anyone help me to plot the discrete distribution function and the histogram of the continuous distribution function on the same plot?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears that the data involved is not extensive.  Can you include your data?

Comment: The vertical axis variable appears to be a proportion NOT based on a ratio of counts which would result from a sampling from a probability distribution.  If so, then you can't be fitting probability distributions (discrete or continuous) as there would be no random sample.  If you do give the data from a random sample, then the counts are essential.

Comment: Of course, the data is `II` = {0., 0.233333, 0.530303, 0.806061, 1.08182, 1.37879, 1.67576, 1.99394, 2.33333}

And `Fexp` = {0.25286, 0.195293, 0.150842, 0.115864, 0.0896305, 0.0692268, 0.0531954, 0.0412446, 0.0318443}

This discrete distribution is essentially exponential, using the above data I found the parameters of the Gamma Distribution Function that represents it.

Comment: @JimB Sorry, I forgot to say that the continuous distribution (`Fanaly`) is a Gamma Distribuition:

`Fanaly[x_] := x^(\[Lambda] - 1)*Exp[-x/\[Sigma]]/Gamma[\[Lambda]]/(\[Sigma]^\[Lambda]);`

Where lambda = 1, and sigma = 0.657052.